# Upgrade multiple apps to one app

Tags: java, android, google-play

I currently have a few apps in the Play Store about different ships. Is there a way to upgrade all these apps to one consolidated app?

Comment: You could replace the individual apps with a stub that asks the user to install the new app.

Comment: Yea that's what I figured. I was hoping that there would be a seamless way to upgrade

Comment: I would suggest you not replace the Application with a Stub on a single update. Release an additional release of the application with a "nag notice" which allows them to switch over. Be sure to tell them of all the benefits of your new combined app.  Then some time after this then replace the App with a Stub.  This will give your user more of a grace period.

Comment: @ddcruver Yea, that's basically what I decided to do. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite possible to do what you want since all your apps use a different `package name`. As Henry suggested, you can update all your apps and tell the user to install the new app.

The other (not so recommended) option would be to create your consolidated app and generate a different apk for each app you already have on the Store, modifying only the `package name`. All the users will be able to have the consolidated app without the need to install a new app. However, it is a bad approach since you will have many copies of the same app in the store, which may lead you into troubles (not so easy to maintain and probably problems with Google).